# Could Prestashop be used to build a craigslist clone?

Tags: prestashop

I'm not so much interested in actually doing this as knowing if Prestashop has the power to allow members to create their own products, classifieds, etc. I've read some articles on Prestashop and played around with it a bit and it looks like the shop owner has to do all the creating and the users consume.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make client add there own products etc. using prestashop you need to promote all of them at least to managers and grant access to back-office.

But prestashop is just framework as all CMS are. If you have plenty amount of time it is possible to make everything using prestashop source code...

... question is: is it worth?

Answer (score 0):

Especially with the addition of the Webservice in Prestashop 1.4 onwards there's no reason why you couldn't write your own simple "control panel" to give ordinary users some capabilities for creating and managing their own "products".

Obviously you would need to add your own permission scheme (including "ownership") for the products they created, as well as creating the actual product create/edit front end for them.

Definitely possible but non-trivial.

Paul